# cakephp callback before every database operation

Tags: cakephp, logging

Recently my records started to disappear from my application's database so I want to log every database operation cakephp makes. Where should I put the logging commands?

P.S.: This is not the first time cakephp do this to me. Did anybody face this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function beforeSave() in model.

```
public function beforeSave(){
// code for logging
}
```

You can put it in AppModel.php. It's called before saving to DB.

Edit:

Well, I have found something and I hope it will help you: 
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/rainchen/2009/03/09/how-to-debug-as-in-rails

Comment: This function only runs before any save related operation. I want to log every operation like delete update, etc...

Comment: If you find this answer correct, please mark it as a "correct answer". :)

Comment: I agree. :) Good luck! ^^ And if you make it, feel free to post the code here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make your own [`DatabaseLoggerClass`](http://blog.jandorsman.com/2011/05/database-logging-in-cakephp/). Or
[this article](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/alkemann/2008/10/21/logablebehavior) will help you achieve the same what you needed.

[This documentation page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#logging) might also help you to save log for each database operation.

Comment: Thanks for the links (i bookmarked them) but i still don't know where to put the commands.